# On neuron No such file or directory?

Tags: neuron-simulator

I am using neuron, a simulation software on OS. However, when I open nrngui I see the following error.

```
ls: /usr/local/bin/../lib/libpython*.dylib: No such file or directory
<stdin>:114: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
```

What does this mean? How can I fix this ?

Comment: please clarify as to how you're getting this error and whatever code that triggered it.

Comment: I download the Neuron software from https://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/download  on my mac. After that I open nrngui, it comes with a terminal window, And says ls: /usr/local/bin/../lib/libpython*.dylib: No such file or directory :114: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?  I am really confused

Comment: what is ```nrngui```?  is it a script?  a binary?

Comment: This suggests that error may be harmless? https://www.neuron.yale.edu/phpBB/viewtopic.php?t=4295

Comment: nrngui  a part of the neuron software. One icon's name.  @ewong I think it's a part of the software.

Comment: I agree with Justas said. I think should be fine if there is no big program running.  @Justas

Comment: This is fixed in recent versions of NEURON.